# Crystal Reports 2013 Why isn't my variable incrementing

Tags: crystal-reports, increment

In the Group Header I place a variable with this formula: 
Global NumberVar NumZika := 0;

In the details section I place a variable with this formula:
Global NumberVar NumZika :=  Global NumberVar NumZika + 1 ;

It never increments past 1.00 (see screenshot below)

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Global NumberVar NumZika:=0;
NumZika:=tonumber(NumZika)+ 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Initialize in the header section:**

```
    Global NumberVar NumZika:=0;
```

**Increment in the details section:**

```
    WhilePrintingRecords;
    Global NumberVar NumZika:= Global NumberVar NumZika+ 1
```

**Display value in the footer:**

```
    WhilePrintingRecords;
    Global NumberVar NumZika;
```